# IntersectionObserver in useEffect with TypeScript and Next js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intersection-observer

I'm trying to use IntersectionObserver in UseEffect and it works fine but TypeScript is complaining about cachedRef. It says:
*Argument of type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'*.

[I've seen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006379/intersectionobserver-api-and-typescript) but can't figure out how to apply it to my code. If even possible.

```
const StickyNav = ({ children, stuckClasses, unstuckClasses }: Props) => {
  const [stuck, setStuck] = useState(false)
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
  const classes = stuck ? stuckClasses : unstuckClasses

  useEffect(() => {
    const cachedRef = ref.current
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([e]) => setStuck(e.intersectionRatio < 1),
      { threshold: [1], rootMargin: "-91px 0px 91px 0px" }
    )

    // const cachedRef: HTMLDivElement | null
    // Argument of type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
    // Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2345)
    observer.observe(cachedRef)
    return () => observer.unobserve(cachedRef)
  }, [ref])

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <Container>
        {children}
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just needed to check if ref.current exists in useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!ref.current) return
  ...
```